# How to get all the URLs of a website using Crawling process with Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, screen-scraping, web-crawler

How to get all the URLs of a website

Suppose I want to crawl some part of data in a website which in different web pages how to get all the url's list to get into all those similar pages.

suppose in a mobiles website I want to get all mobiles of one brand how can I get them which are in different URL's of the site. I observe the Div tag class is "brand name" for all the mobiles

Div Class"Nokia" .... I want the URLs of the website which have div class as nokia.

Comment: Screen-scraping other peoples' data without permission is frowned upon, so beware.

Comment: Not only "frowned upon", it is likely a violation of copyright or other intellectual property rights, or as most people know it, theft.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a HTML parser such as [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to extract all urls from anchors, forms, ... If the url is not part of the HTML you are parsing you won't be able (other than *guessing*) know what all the possible subdomains and urls exist for a given domain.